# Locked out after chmod 644 in Google Compute Engine SSH console

Tags: lamp, google-cloud-platform

I've setup a wordpress install on Google Compute Engine. I had SFTP working (FileZilla & WinSCP), but only had read-only access. I want to upload a large theme file, so I tried to give owner WRITE permission using chmod 644. I used the SSH connection from the console and entered `sudo chmod 644 /` and now get a 403 forbidden access when visiting the website's domain, the read-only SFTP won't connect, and the SSH connector won't work either!

I believe I should have used chmod 755 for folders, but am now 'locked out'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that ownership for /wordpress folder is given to a user group called `www-data` by default. What fixed the problem was adding myself to the `www-data` user group using the SSH command line console.

Firstly, I deleted the "locked out" project and setup a new Wordpress project with SSH keys from PuTTY, and confirmed I was back with read-only SFTP access.

Then, I accessed the SSH command line console from the GCE user interface (select your project > compute > vm instances > SSH button (under "connect"). 
BTW the SSH button doesn't lead to the console in Safari, but does in Chrome!

Once in the console, I added myself to the `www-data` group by entering:

```
sudo adduser your-username www-data
```

The `your-username` was the first part of my Google Cloud Platform account's email address (e.g. If johnsmith@abc.com, `your-username` is johnsmith). Dots in the first part of an email address may need to be replaced with an underscore (e.g. john.smith = john_smith).

According to the [advice I was following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30629/how-can-i-recursively-change-the-permissions-of-files-and-directories), I then gave ownership of the  `/var/www` folder to the `www-data` group by entering:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Lastly, I granted the group `www-data` write permission of the `/var/www` folder by entering:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

After entering these 3 commands, I closed the SSH command line console, disconnected the SFTP (filezilla) and reconnected again and could add files to /wordpress and sub-folders.

It would be great if anyone with a security background could confirm this is OK and/or add a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

- delete affected instance, but ensure to leave the disk around
- [mount the disk to another running instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attachdiskrunninginstance)
- manually restore filesystem permissions on that disk or just copy your data to new location
- after configuration has been restored, consider creating regular [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#snapshots) of your disks for backup purposes

Comment: Is that equivalent to starting again? If so, how do I use chmod correctly to give WRITE permission to the owner?

Comment: @jamese not exactly, these steps would allow you to bring things back to status quo before FS permissions modification. If you didn't lose lots of work due to this issue, it might actually make sense to start over from scratch. I believe that giving write permissions to the owner should be a separate question on its own. Cheers,